# Is there a triple store to manage OWL as named graph and compatible with OWL-api?

Tags: owl, triplestore, owl-api

I am working on a project focused on OWL. Recently we came up with the requirement to deal with multiple owl ontologies interconnected with each other using the named graph appraoch.

I have two questions on the matter:

1-Is there any tool (i suppose triple store) that support that ?

2-Is there any tool that would allow me to keep working with the OWL API, to update my ontologies at runtime while providing me a owl store facility ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple ontologies and storing them in different named graphs is not a problem at all and can be done in any triple store. However, if ontologies are interconnected, and you want to take advantage of the interconnection, then you won't probably have direct support for your case with an out of the box solution. But it depends on what you mean by "interconnected". Does it mean the ontologies import others? Does it mean you have ontology alignments connecting the ontologies? Do you have other types of links between ontologies? Transformation rules from ontology instances to other ontology instances? Etc.

As for your second question, I'd say you can probably do that with a number of tools, but you would have to add your own custom code to make it all work together as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Well, to cut the story short. I want to use named graph to implement reification. Hence it would be more to have a statement in the default ontology such as "Jhon said <namedGraph>", and in the named graph, have a set of statements. Then from time to time check if the named graph is indeed entailed by the default graph. The second part is not so important for now. What is really important is that we want to be able to have named graph that talks about the default graph, stating fact that can be true or false in the default graph